# progress bar in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project, on a particular view I am having various ajax calls and during the access to the database and displaying the data, it`s taking a long time.  I want to have something like a progress image pops up, that would be displaying till the data are displayed and making the view where the data would be displayed as a modal, such that the user can no more click on anything on that page.  Can I have an idea or guide how can I achieve that?  Is there the possiblilty of progress bar in MVC or any suggestion is welcomed, any example please.

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill if you've not already got jQuery and jQuery-UI on your site, it can be done by creating a modal dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal
that contains a progress bar: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

You can then poll the server for the progress and update the appearance of the progress bar.